# I'm not a programmer. Just need to know if DART is an alternative to JAVA

Tags: javascript

I am not a programmer and really did not know how much of the work I do online, relies on JAVA.
Now that everyone has been asked to disable it- I have not been able to find any info,  on potential alternatives.  None of the articles sharing the information mention any alternative.  Did Google just not market this thing? I'm confused.

**Can I just download DART** and have it run INSTEAD of my JAVA?**  And then be able to continue on business as usual?  Or is it way more complicated than that?

EX- If my Chrome stopped working. I would have other options to download, like FireFox or IE and continue on with work.

I just want to be able to use my computer like I do when Java is enabled.
Is DART the type of software that will help me to do that?

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated!!!!!
Thank you so much!
: )

Comment: They're not the same thing at all. Not interchangeable.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with DART, but according to the wiki, it seems a replacement for **Javascript** and **not Java**, which are two very different languages. Are you confident Java has been requested disabled? (I find Javascript more likely, due to security issues)

Comment: If javascript IS the thing you're required to disable, your job musn't directly depend on it and your normal tasks shouldn't be inhibited by a lack there of _(Users of Apple products have largely survived without it)_.

Comment: @AntiEarth "Apple users have mostly survived without it" doesn't make any sense. Are *you* confusing Java with JavaScript?

Comment: Forgive my grammar. I've not had to think all holidays. :)
Also, my post begins "If **javascript** IS the thing you're required to disable".

Comment: @AntiEarth The grammar makes sense but Apple products don't have JavaScript disabled :)

Comment: Oh Good Lord, but I might be confusing flash with javascript...

Comment: @AntiEarth: [US-CERT is recommending to temporarily disable Java in the browser](http://www.us-cert.gov/current/#us_cert_releases_oracle_java), not JavaScript.

Comment: Aha, I see. Welp, think I'll bow out and get back to wasting my time red faced now. :/

Answer (score 1):

DART is not a replacement for Java. DART is a programming language that translates its programs into JavaScript (which, despite its name, is not Java) so that they can run on your browser. You do not need to download DART, unless you want to create your own programs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean that everyone asked you to disable JavaScript, not Java. Currently JavaScript is the only programming language in the browser that works without plugins. So you have no alternatives. Internet serfing with JavaScript disabled will not give you much pleasure.

Comment: [US-CERT is recommending to temporarily disable **Java** in the browser](http://www.us-cert.gov/current/#us_cert_releases_oracle_java).